# How to implement an browser idle system?

Tags: ember.js, browser, idle-processing

What I want to do is to check if the user of my Ember application is in idle mode in the browser, and if so I want to implement some rules. Please check the following example.

```
if (User is idle)
   transition to template1
else
   transition to index
```

I need to do this for every template of my application.

Can anyone please suggest a solution or an example for this example?

Comment: What do you mean by "idle"?

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I needed http://emberjs.jsbin.com/laxomesi/2/edit (Many thanks @panta82), but if you still have other solutions you may post them !